# Why did git reject hunks?

Tags: git, patch

I create a branch called test4, which remote git does not know about because I have never pushed commits. I edit some files and create a patch with this command:

`git diff <upstreamBranchName> --ignore-submodules > myPatch.patch`

In this case, master is the upstream.

This is the patch file:

```
diff --git a/Makefile b/Makefile
index 0f4ad51..79428ba 100644
--- a/Makefile
+++ b/Makefile
@@ -25,9 +25,17 @@ publish: ## Builds this branch's publishable HTML and other artifacts under buil
    giza make publish
    if [ ${GIT_BRANCH} = master ]; then redirects config/redirects -o build/public/.htaccess; fi

-stage: ## Host online for review
-   publish build/${GIT_BRANCH}/html ${STAGING_BUCKET} --prefix=${PROJECT} --stage ${ARGS}
-   @echo "Hosted at ${STAGING_URL}/${PROJECT}/${USER}/${GIT_BRANCH}/index.html"
+%: 
+    @: 
+
+
+# $(MAKECMDGOALS) is the list of "targets" spelled out on the command line
+stage: 
+   git clone https://github.com/me/test-submodules.git scripts
+   cd scripts 
+   node scripts/app.js $(filter-out $@,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
+   #rm -rf scripts
+

 deploy: build/public ## Deploy to the production bucket
    publish build/public ${PRODUCTION_BUCKET} --prefix=${PROJECT} --deploy --redirect-prefix='bi-connector' ${ARGS}
diff --git a/source/tutorial/install.txt b/source/tutorial/install.txt
index 4e9c4b6..b2f9f8f 100644
--- a/source/tutorial/install.txt
+++ b/source/tutorial/install.txt
@@ -10,10 +10,11 @@ Install  on Windows



-
 MADDIE WAS HERE AND HERE HERE


+asdadasd
+
 .. default-domain:: me

 .. contents:: On this page
```

On a clean clone of the repo, on the master branch, if I apply the patch with `patch -p1 < mypatch.patch" inside a program, I get:

```
Error: Command failed: cd repos/docs && patch -p1 < /tmp/myPatch.patch

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:295:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
Error applying patch:  Error: Command failed: cd repos/docs_newHead && patch -p1 < /tmp/myPatch.patch

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:295:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5) {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'cd repos/docs-bi-connector_newHead && patch -p1 < /tmp/myPatch.patch',
  stdout: 'patching file Makefile\n' +
    'patching file source/tutorial/install.txt\n' +
    'Hunk #1 FAILED at 10.\n' +
    '1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file source/tutorial/install.txt.rej\n',
  stderr: ''
}
```

Why are the hunks failing?

Comment: Looks like the diff is not against master?

Comment: it is: I printed my command before executing it in my program, `git diff master --ignore-submodules > myPatch.patch`

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have anything to do with Git itself.

Your patch says to change two files, and supplies expected context along with some "delete these lines and insert these lines instead" along with those two files.  The `patch` command—which is not Git's; it's an independent program—is complaining that one of these two files does not match the expected context, or does not have the expected lines that are to be changed:

```
  stdout: 'patching file Makefile\n' +
    'patching file source/tutorial/install.txt\n' +
    'Hunk #1 FAILED at 10.\n' +
    '1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file source/tutorial/install.txt.rej\n',
```

says that `patch` itself printed:

> ```
> patching file Makefile
> patching file source/tutorial/install.txt
> Hunk #1 FAILED at 10.
> 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file source/tutorial/install.txt.rej
> ```

You could go to whichever system is actually running these commands and inspect its files, but in general, this means that the diff against file `Makefile` worked: `patch` was able to apply it.  The diff against `source/tutorial/install.txt` did not: either the context did not match, or the lines that were to be deleted did not exist in the form shown in your diff, or both.

We can see your diff, but we cannot see the file you're asking that other machine to use when you ask it to apply your diff to `source/tutorial/install.txt`, so we cannot say *why* the patch fails.  But again, this has nothing to do with Git itself: Git is producing a patch, but you're using a non-Git program to *apply* the patch.

If you have the other computer use `git apply` to apply a patch, it is very likely to fail, as the problem is almost certainly simply that the file on the other machine doesn't match the file you used to *generate* the patch in the first place.  (Note that the `Makefile` file *did* match enough; it was the *other* file where the problem occurred.)

If you have the other computer use `git apply -3`, the other computer can use the `index 4e9c4b6..b2f9f8f 100644` line to attempt to reconstruct the original version of the file and perform a three-way merge.  To make this more effective, use `--full-index` when generating the patch.  (Consider using `git format-patch` to create the patch, if you're going to use this somewhat crude and primitive method that some people still prefer.)